# Monogame/XNA Input listener or execute function on click?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm creating a menu system for my game, and am trying to make the buttons so that on creation, I can pass a set of instructions (or function) to execute on a click event.

I have a function called `ChangeScreen`,  which takes an `enum` parameter, `Screen`, and I'd like to be able to pass this function into the button listen event, like so (pseudo-code incoming):

`menuButtons.Add( new MenuButton(ChangeScreen(Screen.Settings), texture, hovertexture, position) );`

I'd then enumerate over `menuButtons` and call each button's `Update` and `Draw` methods. I love this idea, it seems relatively more efficient than assigning each `MenuButton` to it's own variable, rather than writing if statements to check each button specifically.

That's not  the only use case I'd like though. If it is possible, I would love to be able to pass in a method like:

`menuButtons.Add( new MenuButton(new Method() { variableToSet = 1; }, texture, hovertexture, position) );`

I tried using `Action` but I just don't understand how to go about doing this correctly. Is at all possible, or is there a similar solution?

Comment: So you want to create some kind of callback whenever your UI element is pressed?

Comment: Yes, but I want to be able to pass a brand new function in the creation of the MenuButton.

Comment: I don't think it's really clear what you're asking. Maybe try rewording your question and you might get more answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured out a solution that's as close as I can get.

In my `MenuButton` object, I have

```
public delegate void ButtonEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
public event ButtonEventHandler onClick;
```

When I want to check for a click in `Update()`:

```
if (onClick != null && onClick.GetInvocationList().Length > 0)
{
    OnClick(new EventArgs());
}
```

Then, when I create each button, it looks something like this:

```
MenuButton button = new MenuButton();
button.onClick += MethodToExecute;
menuButtons.Add(button);
```

`MethodToExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)` contains whatever actions I want the button to take.

Then I just simply loop through `menuButtons` to update and draw each as needed!